# When using Excel's TEXT() function, how do I create a number code to give me left filling with spaces (a la the built-in "Accounting" code)?

Tags: excel, string-formatting, number-formatting

In Excel, the typical number format code for "Accounting" is:

```
_(* #,##0.00_);_(* (#,##0.00);_(* "-"??_);_(@_)
```

A key aspect of that is the "* " in the +;-;0; components since it right justifies the number around the decimal point, modulo some tweaking for the parens in negatives. And that right alignment is immune to the user subsequently changing the actual alignment of the cell. Or rather, the user may well be getting central or left alignment if they ask for it, but the "* " stuffs in enough spaces so as to shove the visible number back over to the right, no matter what the user does.

I'd like to emulate that behavior in numbers rendered as text using the TEXT() function, but I'm unable to get the "* " behavior. So instead of formatting the cell in question with the above code, I simply format the cell as "General" and rely on the following formula:

```
=TEXT(<my-number-reference>, "_(* #,##0.00_);_(* (#,##0.00);_(* -??_);_(* @_)")
```

The format string is identical to the earlier one apart from removing the quotes around the dash in the ;;0; component. And it gives me strings formatted as numbers in the way I'd expect, *except* for the "* " aspect. The left filling with spaces doesn't appear to be happening at all.

Is it just that the number codes available for TEXT() are only a subset of those available in the cell's actual formatting? Or am I doing something wrong?

(I'm using Excel in a current and up to date installation of Office365, and on both Mac and Windows).